# DS-5501 paragraph meaning

Tags: usa

I would like to know the meaning of this paragraph in the DS-5501 US visa instructions:

> "All selectees, including family members, must be issued by September
>   30, 2019. Under no circumstances can the Department of State issue DVs
>   or approve adjustments after this date, nor can family members obtain
>   DVs to follow-to-join the principal applicant in the United States
>   after this date. "

Answer (score 2):

It means that if you are selected you must complete all the additional administrative steps to get your visa issued before the indicated date.  If any family members will be immigrating with you, or following after you to join you, they must also have their visas before that date.

Anyone whose visa isn't issued by that date has missed the chance to immigrate to the US through that instance of the DV lottery.